# How to set attributes dynamically while creating combobox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am trying to convert a drop down in searchable combo box using jquery. Below code is working fine for me but need to set onkeypress event , onchange event , id , name , maxlength attributes value dynamically.
    I am using below jquery code to create a combo box :

```
 (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var input,
        that = this, 
        wasOpen = false, 
        select = this.element.hide(),
        selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.val() : "",
        wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" ).insertAfter( select );

        input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( wrapper ).val(value).attr( "title", "" )
            .attr("onchange","return pincodeValidation(this.value);")
            .attr("onkeypress","return fnNotAlphabet(event);")
            .attr("maxlength","6")
            .attr("id","pinCode")
            .attr("name","pinCode")
            .autocomplete({// code for autocomplete});
        });
      })(jQuery );
```

How can i set these elements attributes dynamically instead of make changes directly 
 in JavaScript file ?

Comment: Why are you using inline attribute to set events? Use jquery .on() instead

Comment: I am calling combobox on my dropdown id like $("#pincode").combobox(); here pincode is a dropdown, if i use .on() it will change event for dropdown instead of input element which is created dynamicaly using above jquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using attr() you should use [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) Hope this helps

Comment: bind() or on() which is now prefered version

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for the same,but didnt find a soultion .So I changed code to trigger onkeypress on selection of an item in combo box.

```
$( "#countryInput" ).combobox({ 
    select: function (event, ui) { 
       $( "#countryInput" ).trigger('keypress');
}
});
```